# Making primeng table responsive without adding horizontal scrollbar to all the screen but only to the table itself

Tags: angular, html-table, responsive, primeng

I have a table with lots of columns, when I switch to a laptop all the text bumps into each other.

I tried using responsiveLayout="scroll" but it creates 2 scrollbars one for the table (which is good) but also another one to all the screen making it difficult to read the needed content.

Is there a way to put only a scrollbar on the table (including the headers) and not for all the screen?

`<p-table #dt [value]="detail_records" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [totalRecords]="detail_records.length" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, 30, 50]" [globalFilterFields]="[ 'status', 'submission', 'recipient', 'ditribution', 'group', 'user', 'file', 'reference', 'detail', '' ]" dataKey="file" (onFilter)="onFilter($event)" class="ui-table-striped" rowExpandMode="single"> </p-table>`

Sorry for the image because of company policy I had to hide data. but you can clearly see the two scroll bars.

Thank you,

I tried to use the responsiveLayout scroll to make only the table scrollable.

I also tried to set a max-width but it doesn't work.

[image: Screenshot of double scrollbar]

Answer (score 0):

Add `[scrollHeight]="'flex'" [scrollable]="true"` to your `<p-table>`. Also consider adding a `min-height` and `min-height` to the parent `<div>`.

You can also try to play around with `.p-datatable-wrapper` in your .css file like so:
`:host ::ng-deep .p-datatable-wrapper {min-width: 100vw;}`